# jq if value contains then append

Tags: json, bash, if-statement, jq

This might not be the ideal way to approach this but I am working on bulk update of some Grafana dashboards. When the expr key contains value that includes something like "sum((rate" I want to append to the value another string.  Is this even possible?

```
 if (.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr | contains("sum((rate")) then . += "TEST" end'
```

I've tried a few variations of then action and even removed the concatanation to see if I could get simple replace. But getting

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [update-assign](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Update-assignment:%7C=) part of your objects:

```
.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr |= if contains("sum((rate") then . + "TEST" else . end
```

It's also possible to do without the `if` conditional, by first [selecting](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#select(boolean_expression)) all the interesting paths and then modifying only them:

```
(.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr | select(contains("sum((rate"))) += "TEST"
```

Comment: Thanks @knittl issue I have now is the text to append has a lot of special characters.
I tried `+= @text {"text":") * ${}"} but the '{' is unexpected`

Comment: @NicholasTripp `{` can occur inside quotes, but the quoting looks off. Are you trying to add new properties to your object? Can you ask a new question with details? Make sure to include simplified example input and expected output.

Comment: @NicholasTripp and `@text` is a filter, so it must be used as `…|@text` (could require parentheses, depending on your expression)

Answer (score 0):

You always need an `else` branch. For readability you can also pull the target up front (otherwise `.` will match the previous context).

```bash
.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr |=
  if contains("sum((rate") then . + "TEST" else . end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QifxQ6xeCFS)

```bash
.dashboard.panels[].targets[].expr |= . +
  if contains("sum((rate") then "TEST" else "" end
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ItHNfv53mPS)

Comment: Cool, guess this: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/ 
if A then B end is the same as if A then B else . end. That is, the else branch is optional, and if absent is the same as ..
might be mistaken ...

Comment: jq: error (at <stdin>:3127): object ({"meta":{"t...) and string ("sum((rate(...) cannot have their containment checked

 this as using above

Comment: @NicholasTripp Apparently `if A then B end` as a shortcut to `if A then B else . end` was introduced with v1.6. Yet, the (maybe implied) context `.` always refers to that from the `if` statement itself. Thus, if you put the path inside the condition, it will not be used in any (in your case: the `then`) branch.